# How to send a big tso packet using tcpreplay or other tools on linux

Tags: linux, mtu, tcpreplay

I want to send a big tso packet in a pcap file using tcpreplay.
this pcap file was catpured in the same nic interface.
But when using tcpreplay to send this pcap on the same nic interface, it reported message too long.

The purpose of this case is to test the tso flow, I want to emulate the tso flow, OS send a big tcp packet then the nic will segment this big tcp packet to many small tcp packets.

Do you have suggestion for this flow?
Thanks!

The following is the command and the log:

tcpreplay --loop=10 -i br0 tcp.big.pcap
processing file: tcp.big.pcap
Warning: Unable to send packet: Error with PF_PACKET send() [91]: Message too long (errno = 90)

[root@yunsilicon ~]# hexdump tcp.big.pcap | head
0000000 c3d4 a1b2 0002 0004 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0004 0001 0000 1ca2 65f6 f4c5 000a
0000020 2232 0000 2232 0000 6702 4533 0003 6702
0000030 4533 0002 0008 0045 2422 3039 0040 0640
0000040 4896 a8c0 04e4 a8c0 05e4 228c 8913 3616
0000050 f9c4 cf69 b840 1080 e500 726b 0000 0101
0000060 0a08 9166 d1d2 9472 97a2 3332 3534 3736
0000070 3938 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332
0000080 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938
0000090 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332 3534

The following is the command and the log:

tcpreplay --loop=10 -i br0 tcp.big.pcap
processing file: tcp.big.pcap
Warning: Unable to send packet: Error with PF_PACKET send() [91]: Message too long (errno = 90)

[root@yunsilicon ~]# hexdump tcp.big.pcap | head
0000000 c3d4 a1b2 0002 0004 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0004 0001 0000 1ca2 65f6 f4c5 000a
0000020 2232 0000 2232 0000 6702 4533 0003 6702
0000030 4533 0002 0008 0045 2422 3039 0040 0640
0000040 4896 a8c0 04e4 a8c0 05e4 228c 8913 3616
0000050 f9c4 cf69 b840 1080 e500 726b 0000 0101
0000060 0a08 9166 d1d2 9472 97a2 3332 3534 3736
0000070 3938 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332
0000080 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938
0000090 3130 3332 3534 3736 3938 3130 3332 3534

Comment: Seems like a very specific problem, I would look around tcpreplay source code myself.

[I found this comment, which hints that this is an edge case.](https://github.com/appneta/tcpreplay/blob/43693c4a92dda227a5134ae5e71a7247ae345323/src/fragroute/pkt.c#L141-L143).

I would create an issue on the repository itself.